# How can we parse the text using python regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the following text, and I want the output in a dictionary format.

```
text = '''
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622

197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554

156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701

100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
'''
```

I tried with the following approach but was able to get 2 dictionaries whereas I expect to return 4.

```
names = []

for item in re.finditer("(?P<host>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\s-\s(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s\[(?P<time>\d{2}\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\s-\d{4})\]\s\"(?P<request>[a-zA-Z]+\s\/[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\/\d{1}\.\d{1})\"", text):
    item.groupdict()
    names.append(item.groupdict())
            
print(names)
```

Can any please help me with this?

Comment: `re.finditer(r'^(?P<host>[^-\s]+)\s*-\s*(?P<user_name>\S+)\s+\[(?P<date>[^]]+)\]\s+"(?P<request>[^"]+)"', text, re.M)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the string you are trying to match:

```
"DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0"
```

does not match your regular expression because it expects everything after `DELETE /` to be alphabetic. The requests that match are:

```
POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1
PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0
```

and the ones that do not are

```
DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0
DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1
```

Change the `request` part of the regex to recognize `/` and `+` in addition to alpha characters:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+\s\/[a-zA-Z/+]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\/\d{1}\.\d{1}\"
                     ↑↑
```

instead of

```
"[a-zA-Z]+\s\/[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\/\d{1}\.\d{1}\"
```